# Real time update as user entering information like what Google doc do or use a save button

Tags: design, javascript, ui

I am making a design decision to real time hit API to save all the fields in a form when user make an change even if hes not finished yet. Or, use a save button like most app does.

Any pros and cons other than

pro : real time will generate much more API calls thus heavier server / db load

con : user won't lose any data and is hassle free

Comment: see [What is the problem with "Pros and Cons"?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6758/31260)

Comment: This is more of a UX question. See [here](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/12289/guidelines-for-when-to-auto-save-settings-vs-save-button) and [here](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/2754/autosave-ui-pattern) and [here](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/82588/whats-the-rationale-behind-googles-no-save-approach) and [here](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/9619/why-dont-we-auto-save-for-users-instead-of-having-them-save-manually) among many others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides more traffic to the server, there's a considerable amount of extra work in implementing an auto-save system.

Most of that extra work will revolve around making sure the object (and application) is in a state to be able to save.  Often times, in a UI model, things can get into a state that's not quite reasonable for saving to the system - this is why we generally have validations (so to speak).

Then you have to consider when you're going to trigger these.  After any update to the model?  Ok, fair enough, but you have to code it accordingly.  At a timer interval?  That's tough... never know what might be going on at a timer interval.

I think implementing an auto-save system such as you might see with Google Docs is a fairly considerable project above and beyond having a save button.  I suppose much of it depends on the application though... for some scenarios, it may be worth it (word processing), for others, maybe not so much (business data entry).